# Which coordinate format is this?

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, falconview

How to split these coordinates to degrees, minutes and seconds?

```
E0732931.00 and N30 2025.20
```

Is it 73 degrees, 29 mins and 31 seconds. To convert it to decimal degree, i have to

```
73+39/60+31/3600?
```

N30 2025.20 is 30 degs, 20 minutes, 25 seconds? What is the value after the decimal?

2nd i want to ask that is there any coordinate system which uses 100 seconds in a minute, i.e.

```
decimal degrees = 73+39/60+31/(60*100) ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asumption are correct.
Further:

> > What is the value after the decimal?

the fraction of seconds: so 25.20 seconds

> > is there any coordinate system which uses 100 seconds in a minute, i.e.

No! There are other systems like DM which uses Degrees and decimal minutes: e.g 23 deg 17.1234 minutes